# How to limit car speed with a ELM327 converter?

Tags: obd

There are plenty third party devices which allows to never go faster than speed limits.

But when having already a ELM327 ᴏʙᴅ2 converter, why not using it directly through an android tablet instead of purschasing a separate device ?

Comment: Because it isn't designed for Android?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths it can work with android but this is just the converter hardware. It’s like a bluetooth to ᴜꜱʙ cable : without software it does nothing. And I don’t only to collect data but to write and act on commands.

Comment: Sounds more like a developer/programming topic which is off-topic.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths if there is an app which already exists, then no.

Comment: Revise your question then, because that's not exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths or you can suggest an edit because it's clear that I don't want a programming answer as per currently written.